# Jquery undefined for jquery.parent().attr()

Tags: jquery, mustache

This is the parent div, it's a  html template created using Moustache.js

```
<div class="downloadReport" param ="{{#params}}{{id}}{{/params}}"><a href="#">
<img class="downloadMVReportFromAdmin" alt ="{{mainTitle}}" src="{{indexPageImageURL}}"  
/><br/>'
'<input type="button" id="{{id}}-button" value="Download"   
class="downloadMVReportFromAdmin" param="{{#params}}{{paramValue}}{{/params}}"/></a>
</div>'
```

i am trying to use

```
$(.downloadMVReportFromAdmin).live('click',function(){
    var url = $(this).parent('.downloadReport').attr("param");
    alert(url);
}
```

Iam getting undefined value for the variable url
I am just following the syntax given for jquery.parent() in the jquery site. Please correct me if am wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you should use `.closest` instead of `.parent`

`.parent` only matches the immediate parent, whereas `.closest` walks up the DOM until it finds a match against your selector.

Answer (score 1):

missing quotes, and need another parent() call

```
$('.downloadMVReportFromAdmin').live('click',function(){
var url = $(this).parent().parent('.downloadReport').attr("param");
alert(url);
});
```